# the usage of global keyword in TCL

Tags: tcl, global

I have a question about `global` in TCL.
In one tcl file tclone.tcl, I have a global variable: `global SIGNAL`

in another tcl file called tcltwo.tcl, I set the variable SIGNAL as: `set SIGNAL 10`

In tclone.tcl, I improted the tcltwo.tcl as following" `package require tcltwo.tcl`
will the variable SIGNAL in tclone.tcl will be set as 10 when I execute it? and what is the usage of gloable variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in [its manual page](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/global.htm), the `global` command only has meaning inside proc bodies:

> This command has no effect unless executed in the context of a proc body.

So the whole question is unclear.  If you meant that you have a proc in the first file setting a global variable and another proc (in the second file) reading it, then the question makes sense and the answer is yes, the code from the second file will see the change made by the code from the first file provided the "setting" procedure runs before the "getting" one.  To possibly make it more clear, a global variable is global with regard to an interpreter the code operating that variable runs.  Hence no matter which way do you use to fetch the code into an interpreter (`package require` vs `source` vs `eval` etc), all that code will see the same set of globals.

But in any case you should probably abstrain from using globals and use namespaced variables: they are also global but you greatly reduce the risk of introducing some other code later which will inadvertently mess with that global variable it should not touch.  Of course, as usually this depends on how complicated your application is expected to be.

Comment: By the way, the name of your variable suggests you're possibly intend to use it for some sort of synchronisation between different parts of the program. If so, you should possibly look at uevent (http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/uevent.html) instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: the question is: there is a global SIGNAL in a proc of the first file, and there is a set SIGNAL 10 in the second file, but not in a proc, so I improted the seconde file as following package require tcltwo.tcl will the variable SIGNAL in first file will be set as 10 when I execute it?

Comment: @ratzip, it depends on the context of that `set SIGNAL 10`: if this command is invoked at top level (i.e. not inside any `namespace eval foo ...` or the like, the answer is yes. If that command is invoked in some procedure which has `global SIGNAL` executed *before* the setting command itself, the answer is also yes.  To recap: the outcome of the command `set SIGNAL 10` depends on the context it sees.  Also `set ::SIGNAL 10` will always set the global variable "SIGNAL" no matter what context it's in.

Comment: Globals are the “property” of the application; packages should use their own namespace (especially for variables).